# How can I do responsive pie chart

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I want to do responsive the pie chart in highchart, I need help. My JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hAnCr/512/

```
<div id="container" style="max-width: 618px; height: 275px;"></div>
```

Comment: Well, chart is responsive - when resizing, you can observe different legend. By default, `height` isn't responsive on the webpage. Example with non pie: http://jsfiddle.net/hAnCr/516/ If you want height to be responsive, then call `chart.resize(width, height)` on `resize` event of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Pie charts are created by svg. It will not automatically become responsive, you would have to mesure height and width of the container and call rerender when window diamension changes.

Answer (score 0):

Defaulty chart is responsive, when you set width as 100% (in container styles). (Example http://jsfiddle.net/hAnCr/517/). But in your chart you set a few hardcoded values, which has influence on unresponsibility. So you need to catch `$(windows).resize()` and then calculate new hardcoded values and create chart.